# Python asyncio "contains"

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Can the `__contains__` function by adapted to Python asyncio, where the method becomes a coroutine? For example

```
class A():
    async def __contains__(self, a):
        return True

async def main():
    a = A()
    print(2 in a)
```

Of course this generates the warning

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'A.__contains__' was never awaited

I assume there needs to be some special version of `in` for asyncio, though I've tried several permutations of using `await` and `in` with no luck.

My real use case of `contains` is a wrapper around a database search to check if there is an entity conflict. One case is to check if a user's screen name already exists in a database table, such as `'mike' in Users`

Of course I could make my own `contains` and do something like `User.contains('mike')` but I prefer the beauty of `in`.

Comment: Have you tried `print(await (2 in a))`?

Comment: Yes I did.     `print(await (2 in a))`
`TypeError: object bool can't be used in 'await' expression`

Comment: I don't know much about async, but this got me curious and I found this question: [How to set class attribute with await in \_\_init\_\_](/q/33128325/4518341), where the [top answer](/a/33134213/4518341) says *"Most magic methods aren't designed to work with `async def`/`await`"*. Does that help? I also found this: [python async special class methods \_\_delete\_\_](/q/43268390/4518341)

Comment: Sort of, there are a few magic methods that can be adapted, such as `iter` with `aiter` and `async with` using with `aenter` and `aexit`. I was even able to to adapt `__getitem__` myself. I was hoping there would be something for `__contains__`

Comment: The thing that calls `__contains__` would need to do the await, but that thing is the implementation of the `in` byte code. `in` isn't going to know when its in a coroutine or the target object is waitable. Its the same with other things implemented with magic methods. Python is a hybrid language - async is bolted on a prodedural language - so its not a natural fit for all types of polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

No - the built-in `in` operator is naturally synchronous, and making it make use of an asynchronous iterator needs changes on the language side.

Just see, for an analogy, that when the language introduced support to asynchronous context managers and asynchronous iterators, there where syntax changes introducing the `async with` and `async for` versions.

If you want a hacky toy, not suitable for production anyway, you might play along calling (synchronously) `loop._run_once()` inside your `__contains__` code, where you would yield to the async loop with an `await`. It is an internal structure, so if there is a custom event-loop running this will simply fail - and also, it is not designed to be re-entrant, so if it is called from an asynchronous function, `_run_once` will be on the call stack already: you results might range from it doing nothing, to a lot of estate information both on your async loop and tasks to be corrupted. As a hacky toy, it could be a valid experience though.